# Querying multiple data of a array containing same properties via graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I wish to nested query the array via graphql, by elimination repeated properties. Below is the json file

```
{
  "MAIN_ARRAY": [
    {
      "One": [
        {
          "title": "Title",
          "description": "Description",
          "avatar": "../../assets/image/author-1.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "Two": [
        {
          "title": "Title",
          "description": "Description",
          "avatar": "../../assets/image/author-1.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I dont want to repeat the properties title, description, avatar for One and Two because its the same. Is there any workaround for this to avoid repeating it. Below code didnt work.

```
query {
  fileJson {
    MAIN_ARRAY {
      One, Two {
        title
        description
        avatar
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the underlying types of both `One` & `Two` are the same, you can use [Fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments)

```
query {
  fileJson {
    MAIN_ARRAY {
      One {
        ...MyFragment
      }
      Two {
        ...MyFragment
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment MyFragment on MyType {
  title
  description
  avatar
}
```